# Kotlin Flow Offline Caching

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, kotlin-flow

I am new with kotlin flow and I am working about this document. [Kotlin Flows](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow). In this code every five seconds datasource fetch data from api and emits it.

**This is my example datasource class.**

I am getting data and emitting it.

```
class RemoteDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
private val api:CryptoApi
): RemoteDataSource {


override suspend fun cryptoList(): Flow<List<CryptoCoinDto>> {
    return flow {
        while (true){
            
            val data = api.getCoinList()
            emit(data)
            delay(5000L)
        }
    }
   }
}
```

**This is my example repository.**

I am mapping data and saving it room database. I want to get data from room database and emit it because of single source of truth principle but I still have to return dataSource because if I open new flow{} I can't reach datasource's data. Of course I can fix the problem by using List instead of Flow<List> inside of RemoteDataSource class. But I want to understand this example. How can I apply here single source of truth.

```
class CoinRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val dataSource:RemoteDataSource,
private val dao: CryptoDao
):CoinRepository {

override fun getDataList(): Flow<List<CryptoCoin>> {

     dataSource.cryptoList().map { dtoList ->
        val entityList = dtoList.map { dto ->
            dto.toCryptoEntity()
        }
        dao.insertAll(entityList)
    }
    return dataSource.cryptoList().map {
        it.map { it.toCryptoCoin() }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you need to collect items in two different places, correct?

Comment: I want to save items in room database then collect them from database and emit it as a maindata. For single source of truth principle. I can manage single fetch but this example has multiple emits I can't handle it. @broot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help. I personally wouldn't return a Flow for the API stuff since you are technically speaking returning only 1 list all the time

```
override fun getDataList(): Flow<List<CryptoCoin>> {
    val localFlow = dao.getCryptoCoins()
    val apiFlow = flow<Unit> {
        // Since getDataList can't be suspend due to it returning a flow, we create a new flow simply to run a suspendable function
        getAndSaveCryptoCoinsFromApi()
    }.onStart { // If I don't add this onStart, then it won't work
        emit(Unit)
    }
    
    return localFlow.combine(apiFlow) { dbItems, _ ->
        dbItems
        // We just return DB items. Why? Since we are saving api items to the db, and since the db items return a flow, it will automatically emit values to the flow once new items are added to the db
    }
}

private suspend fun getAndSaveCryptoCoinsFromApi() {
    try {
        val result = api.getCryptoCoins().toDomain()
        val entities = result.map { it.toEntity() }
        dao.insertCoins(entities)
    } catch(e: Exception) { /**/ }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is actually more complicated than it seems. Flows were designed to support back-pressure which means that they usually only produce items on demand, when being consumed. They are passive, instead of pushing items, items are pulled from the flow.

(Disclaimer: this is all true for cold flows, not for hot flows. But `cryptoList()` is a cold flow.)

It was designed this way to greatly simplify cases when the consumer is slower than producer or nobody is consuming items at all. Then producer just stops producing and everything is fine.

In your case there are two consumers, so this is again more complicated. You need to decide what should happen if one consumer is slower than the other. For example, what should happen if nobody collects data from `getDataList()`? There are multiple options, each requires a little different approach:

1. Stop consuming the source flow and therefore stop updating the database.
2. Update the database all the time and queue items if nobody is collecting from `getDataList()`. What if there are more and more items in the queue?
3. Update the database all the time and discard items if nobody is collecting from `getDataList()`.

**Ad.1.**

It can be done by using [onEach()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-each.html):

```kotlin
return dataSource.cryptoList().onEach {
    // update db
}.map {
    it.map { it.toCryptoCoin() }
}
```

In this solution updating the database is a "side effect" of consuming the `getDataList()` flow.

**Ad.2. and Ad.3.**

In this case we can't passively wait until someone asks us for an item. We need to actively consume items from the source flow and push them to the downstream flow. So we need a hot flow: [SharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/index.html). Also, because we remain the active side in this case, we have to launch a coroutine that will do this in the background. So we need a `CoroutineScope`.

Solution depends on your specific needs: do you need a queue or not, what should happen if queue exceeded the size limit, etc., but it will be similar to:

```kotlin
return dataSource.cryptoList().onEach {
    // update db
}.map {
    it.map { it.toCryptoCoin() }
}.shareIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly)
```

You can also read about [buffer()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html) and [MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow.html) - they could be useful to you.

Comment: I think, I get it but there is something I can't understand. All of these update db and mapping items it's okay but It still collects the data from api. Can I collect data from room and emit it ? or do I think completely wrong ? I am confused about single source of truth I think. I just wanted to listen real time changes and save it to database then collect them from database and send them to ui. @broot